# Why I get Object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have many-to-many relationship between two entities: Tag and Ads. When User wants to create ad, he need to insert few tags. But when I try to create add I am getting this error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-10-11T21:21:44.752+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.mybrocki.entity.Tag; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.mybrocki.entity.Tag",
    "path": "/mybrocki/auth/ads/create"
}
```

This is my Tag entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Tags")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "adsTags",  cascade = {
            CascadeType.ALL
        })
    private Set<Ads> ads;
    
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Ads> getAds() {
        return ads;
    }

    public void setAds(Set<Ads> ads) {
        this.ads = ads;
    }
```

And this is Ads entity:

```
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "tags_ads",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ads_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Tag> adsTags;
```

And this is service implementation class:

```
ads.setVisibleAds(false);
                    ads.setAdsTags(new ArrayList<Tag>());
                    if (!adsDTO.getTags().isEmpty()) {
                        for (Tag tagDTO : adsDTO.getTags()) {
                    ads.getAdsTags().add(tagDTO); }
                    

                    }
                    ads.setStatus(AdsStatus.READYFORREVIEW.toString());
                    ads.setAdssubgroup(adsSubGroupRepository.findOneById(adsDTO.getAdsSubGroupId()));
                    ads.setFixedPrice(adsDTO.getFixedPrice());
                    ads.setFreeDelivery(adsDTO.getFreeDelivery());
                    ads.setProductWarranty(adsDTO.getProductWarranty());
                    ads.setUrgentSales(adsDTO.getUrgentSales());
                    Date currentDate = new Date();
                    Instant instant = currentDate.toInstant();
                    LocalDateTime ldt = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
                    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    
                    adsDTO.setAdsDate(currentDate);
                    ads.setAdsDate(adsDTO.getAdsDate());
                    
                    adsRepository.save(ads);
```

This is json:

```
{
  "adsGroupId": 5,
  "adsSubGroupId": 27,
  "adsType": "USED",
  "description": "Ford fiesta 1.3",
  "fixedPrice": false,
  "freeDelivery": false,
  "image": [
    "http://res.cloudinary.com/mybrocki/image/upload/v1589887253/s5d11rshydka5nov2wox.jpg,http://res.cloudinary.com/mybrocki/image/upload/v1589887253/s5d11rshydka5nov2wox.jpg,"
  ],
  "price": 800,
  "productName": "FOcscscsdcRD Goragjhggiujkjhkjoijiohiuhn",
  "productWarranty": false,
  "urgentSales": true,
    "tags": [
        {
        "name":"Second hand"
    }]
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please put error messages and JSON in your question as text, not images.

Comment: @tgdavies I updated it, please take a look...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `cascade = {CascadeType.ALL }` on your `Tag` class but not on your `Ads` class, if you want to save your `Ads` object and cascade save the `Tag` objects in it, then you need the annotation on the field of your `Ads` class. Otherwise save the `Tag` object instead of the `Ads` object.